# Row Editing event not firing on Edit button click

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with edit and delete buttons on each row.
I am trying to change the back color or the fore color of the row in the gridview on which the edit button is clicked.

I am using the Row Editing event .Below is my code, the row editing event is not getting fired when I click the edit button.

```
  protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearBackColor();

        GridView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.SelectedRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        //GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
        //row.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;

    }
```

What could be wrong? Please let me know.

Comment: Share the code from your Page_Load method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx. You are probably missing CommandName="Edit" on button, so RowEditing will never fire.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line : `GridView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewEditIndex;`
right click on gridview, and click properties. Check for "EditRowStyle",expand it, there will be BackColor, choose the color you want, and its done.

Comment: The event GridView1_Rowediting is not getting fired when I click on the edit button